# Add class to selected paragraph (contenteditable div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of paragraphs like this in a `contenteditable` div:

```
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
```

I want to be able to select one of the paragraghs (with the mouse) and add a class to it:

```
<p>text</p>
<p class="added-class">text</p>
<p>text</p>
```

What's the simplest way to do this?

(I'm going to create my own event but I want the **selected text/paragraph** to be the selected element)

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want a mouse hover over or mouse click or what? what is the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can do this with jquery.simplest and better solution.

Code:

```
$(function(){

$('p').mouseover(function()
{
$(this).addClass('added-class');

});

});
```

Example :http://jsfiddle.net/3rfyLpjm/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is:

```
$("p").on("click", function(){
  $(this).addClass("added-class")
});
```

If you want to have only one p with "added-class"

```
var chosen = null;
$("p").on("click", function(){
  if(chosen) 
    chosen.removeClass("added-class");
  $(this).addClass("added-class")
  chosen = $(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

needn't jQuery:

```
var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
  ps[i].onclick = function(e) { 
    e.target.classList.toggle('click'); 
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it simple using jquery:

**HTML**

```
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('click','p',function(){
    $('p').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('added-class');
    });
    $(this).addClass('added-class');
});
</script>
```